# Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach not running to conclusion

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Here's a failing test. How can I confirm that the loops run the correct number of times?

```
    public Random Randomator { get; set; }
    public const int TimesToRun = 1000000;

    [TestMethod]
    public void ThrowTheDice()
    {
        Randomator = new Random();

        var resultsParallel = new Dictionary<int, int>
        {
            {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}
        };

        var resultsParallelForEach = new Dictionary<int, int>
        {
            {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}
        };

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        Parallel.For(0, TimesToRun, ctr =>
        {
            var val = ThrowDice();
            if (!resultsParallel.ContainsKey(val))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            var existing = resultsParallel[val];
            resultsParallel[val] = existing + 1;
        });

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var parallelTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, TimesToRun);
        Parallel.ForEach(numbers, ctr =>
        {
            var val = ThrowDice();
            if (!resultsParallel.ContainsKey(val))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            var existing = resultsParallelForEach[val];
            resultsParallelForEach[val] = existing + 1;
        });

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var parallelForEachTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        var parallelTotal = resultsParallel.Sum(x => x.Value);
        var parallelForEachTotal = resultsParallelForEach.Sum(x => x.Value);

        Assert.AreEqual(parallelTotal, TimesToRun);
        Assert.AreEqual(parallelForEachTotal, TimesToRun);
    }

    public int ThrowDice()
    {
        return Randomator.Next(1, 7);
    }
```

Comment: `How can I confirm that the loops run the correct number of times?` They are running correct number of times, But you access to the shared object uncontrolled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In parallel, you're running these lines:

```
var existing = resultsParallel[val];
resultsParallel[val] = existing + 1;
```

There's no guarantee that only one thread/task is running those lines at the same time, for any particular `val` value. So two threads can read the value 2, add 1, and store the value 3. You need to use thread-safe methods for accumulating your totals.

E.g. you could use an overload of [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782936%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows each thread to build up its own copy of the results separately and then has a final combining step to allow you to compute the total results:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult For<TLocal>(
    long fromInclusive,
    long toExclusive,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<long, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using hashtable implementations that are not thread-safe. Thus, you only proof you did a mistake. Use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead, which is thread-safe:

```
var resultsParallel = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
Parallel.For(0, TimesToRun, ctr =>
{
    var val = ThrowDice();
    resultsParallel.AddOrUpdate(val, 1, (key, old) => old + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a semaphore to serialize the concurrent Access to resultsParallel, resultsParallelForEach:

public class Example
    {
        public static Random Randomator { get; set; }
        public const int TimesToRun = 1000000;

```
    public static Semaphore semaphore;


    public static void ThrowTheDice()
    {
        Randomator = new Random();

        semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1);

        var resultsParallel = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}
    };

        var resultsParallelForEach = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}
    };

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        Parallel.For(0, TimesToRun, ctr =>
        {
            var val = ThrowDice();
            if (!resultsParallel.ContainsKey(val))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            semaphore.WaitOne();

            var existing = resultsParallel[val];
            resultsParallel[val] = existing + 1;

            semaphore.Release();
        });

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var parallelTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, TimesToRun);
        Parallel.ForEach(numbers, ctr =>
        {
            var val = ThrowDice();
            if (!resultsParallel.ContainsKey(val))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            semaphore.WaitOne();

            var existing = resultsParallelForEach[val];
            resultsParallelForEach[val] = existing + 1;

            semaphore.Release();
        });

        stopwatch.Stop();
        var parallelForEachTime = stopwatch.Elapsed;

        var parallelTotal = resultsParallel.Sum(x => x.Value);
        var parallelForEachTotal = resultsParallelForEach.Sum(x => x.Value);

        Debug.Assert(parallelTotal == TimesToRun);
        Debug.Assert(parallelForEachTotal == TimesToRun);
    }

    public static int ThrowDice()
    {
        return Randomator.Next(1, 7);
    }
}
```